# How to use HOC with redux compose and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have two HOC, which want to use with redux compose, but the compiler doesn't make correct type. Compose declares function is from redux [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts). If we paste the code in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Func1%3CT1%2C%20R%3E%20%3D%20(a1%3A%20T1)%20%3D%3E%20R%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Component%3CProps%3E%20%3D%20(props%3A%20Props)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20compose%3CT1%2C%20A%2C%20R%3E(%0D%0A%20%20f1%3A%20(b%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20R%2C%0D%0A%20%20f2%3A%20Func1%3CT1%2C%20A%3E%0D%0A)%3A%20Func1%3CT1%2C%20R%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20HOC1%3A%20%3CProps%3E(component%3A%20Component%3CProps%3E)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3D%3E%20Component%3CProps%20%26%20%7B%20prop%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20HOC2%3A%20%3CProps%3E(component%3A%20Component%3CProps%3E)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3D%3E%20Component%3CProps%20%26%20%7B%20prop%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20component%3A%20Component%3C%7Bprops%3A%20boolean%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20HOC1(HOC2(component))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20compose(HOC1%2C%20HOC2)(component)%3B). We will see different types of first and second variables.

```
type Func1<T1, R> = (a1: T1) => R

type Component<Props> = (props: Props) => string;

declare function compose<T1, A, R>(
  f1: (b: A) => R,
  f2: Func1<T1, A>
): Func1<T1, R>

declare const HOC1: <Props>(component: Component<Props>)
    => Component<Props & { prop: string }>

declare const HOC2: <Props>(component: Component<Props>)
    => Component<Props & { prop: number }>

declare const component: Component<{props: boolean}>

const first = HOC1(HOC2(component));

const second = compose(HOC1, HOC2)(component);
```

Comment: Your playground link is broken, it's just a playground link, no code

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir sorry, I have updated the link.

Comment: I don't think we can model a good version of `compose` in the current typescript type system. There is no way to capture generic type parameters to the HOCs. This might work for your very specific case, but it is not a true general solution: `declare function compose<A, R, R2>(f1: (b: A) => R,f2: (b: A) => R2,): (<P>(c: Component<P>) => Component<P & R & R2>)`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir It's very sad. 
Please, post your answer separately and I'll check it as correct answer.

Comment: Added the answer, 10x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't model a good version of compose in the current typescript type system. There is no way to capture generic type parameters to the HOCs.

We can create a version that might work in some circumstances based on the way the type parameters get erased (basically they are just replaced with the narrowest type in this case `{}`). This means we can get the props that are added by the HOC. I don't know how well this will work, but it does work for your sample:

```
type Func1<T1, R> = (a1: T1) => R

type Component<Props> = (props: Props) => string;

declare function compose<A, R, R2>(f1: (b: A) => Component<R>,f2: (b: A) => Component<R2>,): (<P>(c: Component<P>) => Component<P & R & R2>)

declare const HOC1: <Props>(component: Component<Props>)
    => Component<Props & { prop1: string }>

declare const HOC2: <Props>(component: Component<Props>)
    => Component<Props & { prop2: number }>

declare const component: Component<{props3: boolean}>

const a = HOC1(HOC2(component));

const b = compose(HOC1, HOC2)(component); //Component<{ props3: boolean; } & { prop1: string; } & { prop2: number; }>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20%20%20%20type%20Func1%3CT1%2C%20R%3E%20%3D%20(a1%3A%20T1)%20%3D%3E%20R%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Component%3CProps%3E%20%3D%20(props%3A%20Props)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20declare%20function%20compose%3CA%2C%20R%2C%20R2%3E(f1%3A%20(b%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Component%3CR%3E%2Cf2%3A%20(b%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Component%3CR2%3E%2C)%3A%20(%3CP%3E(c%3A%20Component%3CP%3E)%20%3D%3E%20Component%3CP%20%26%20R%20%26%20R2%3E)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20declare%20const%20HOC1%3A%20%3CProps%3E(component%3A%20Component%3CProps%3E)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%3E%20Component%3CProps%20%26%20%7B%20prop1%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20declare%20const%20HOC2%3A%20%3CProps%3E(component%3A%20Component%3CProps%3E)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%3E%20Component%3CProps%20%26%20%7B%20prop2%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20declare%20const%20component%3A%20Component%3C%7Bprops3%3A%20boolean%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20a%20%3D%20HOC1(HOC2(component))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20b%20%3D%20compose(HOC1%2C%20HOC2)(component)%3B%20%2F%2FComponent%3C%7B%20props3%3A%20boolean%3B%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20prop2%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%3E)

Comment: here is also nice showcase how to implement compose for react HoC. unfortunately there are only drawbacks, no silver bullet yet :) https://rjzaworski.com/2017/09/typescript-react-compose