# Typescript: Compose HOCs wrapping components with defaultProps in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Trying to compose several HOCs (with compose func) seems to lose props annotations altogether, as if making a proper HOC that doesn't lose it wrapped component's defaulted (therefore optional) props wasn't tricky enough.

Found some nice workarounds to make HOC preserve optional props of wrapped components leveraging `JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes` alias:

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

// wrapper
export interface WithThemeProps {
  theme: string;
}

interface WrapperProps {
  foo: string;
}

function withTheme<
  C extends React.ComponentType<React.ComponentProps<C> & WithThemeProps>,
  ResolvedProps = JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<C, Omit<React.ComponentProps<C>, keyof WithThemeProps>>
>(component: C) {
  return connect<WithThemeProps, void, WrapperProps & ResolvedProps>(() => ({
    theme: 'theme',
  }))(component as React.ComponentType);
}

// component with default props
interface Props extends WithThemeProps {
  message: string;
  required: string;
}

class Component extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    message: '',
  };

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}

// usage
const Wrapped = withTheme(Component);
const el = <Wrapped required="r" foo="f" />; // works

const Composed = compose(withTheme)(Component);
const HeavilyComposed = compose( withTheme, withTheme )(Component);

const x = <Composed required="r" foo="f" />; // wrapped works
const y = <HeavilyComposed required="r" foo="f" />; // error, props are lost altogether
```

Also I came across [an interesting idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54355680/5627824) to model `compose` function to this specific scenario. With a little bit of tweaking of the original answer all props are preserved, but also it made them required, which is not what I expected:

```
const HeavilyComposed = compose( withTheme, withTheme )(Component);
// Type '{ required: string; foo: string; }' is missing the
// following properties from type 'Props': message, theme
const y = <HeavilyComposed required="r" foo="f" />; 

declare function compose<A, R, R2>(
  f1: (b: A) => React.ComponentType<R2>,
  f2: (b: A) => React.ComponentType<R>
): <P>(c: React.ComponentType<P>) => React.ComponentType<P & R & R2>;
```

What should a compose function look like to preserve optional and omitted props?